# Transclude creates a separate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using an accordion angularjs library. It has `transclude:true` on it.

I have a scope variable that I display using the interpolation `{{variable}}`. When I click on the radio buttons, the value it displays is supposed to change.

I set a default radio button and default variable value on load. But it does not show the respective values in the interpolation when I click on other radio buttons.

This worked before using it with the library. I read that `transclude` creates a new scope. 
How do I make this work?

```
<collapsible-item item-title="Configure Maintenance Bill">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <!-- Group of material radios - option 1 -->
       <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="x" name="groupOfMaterialRadios" ng-checked="maintenance_bill_rate_type ==='3' && maintenance_bill_rate_type==='4'"
             ng-model="type" value="expense" ng-change="setCorpusFundDetFn('expense')">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="materialGroupExample1">Expenses</label>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
       <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" ng-disabled="type!='expense'"
          value="3" ng-change="setCorpusFundDetFn()">
       </label>
       <span class="align-middle">Per Flat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
       <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" value="4" ng-disabled="type!='expense'"
          ng-change="setCorpusFundDetFn()">
       </label>
       <span class="align-middle">Per Sqft</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div ng-class="{'has-error': maintenanceBillForm.corpusFundnm.$invalid && maintenanceBillForm.$submitted}">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="carpus_fund" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" placeholder="Enter Corpus Fund"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2 " name="corpusFundnm" required >
             <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">{{corpusFundDet || 'wt'}}</span>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <collapsible-item>
```

Comment: having bindings like 'primaryAction' etc and pass them to collapsible

Comment: @JoeWarner i dont think i completely understand. can you please write as answer

Comment: at work atm in a meeting i'll try get some time later